# USB OTG in Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I would like to connect a USB Mouse, Keyboard or Storage Device to my Nexus 4. So far I know, for this USB OTG must be supported. Unfortunately I can not find any actual information about this.

Does anybody know whether USB OTG is supported by Ubuntu-Touch?
If yes, does anybody know if it would work with a Nexus 4 device?

Comment: I remember that there were some difficulties to get OTG working with Android on the Nexus 4 read the Background section over at http://www.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4 and check your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is supported.

e.g. to mount an USB storage device with an USB-OTG cable: open the terminal and locate the name of the device with the command `sudo fdisk -l`, create a mount point (the directory where you access the device) with the command `sudo mkdir /media/external` and mount the device with `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/external` (if the device was /dev/sda1 and formated with FAT32).

The device can now be accessed with the file-manager. When ready unmount with `sudo umount /media/external`